# How do I make a hollow symmetric matrix with zeros in the main diagonal, ones elsewhere in numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, linear-algebra, identity

In Python numpy, how do I make a hollow symmetric matrix with zeros in the main diagonal, ones elsewhere? e.g.

```
import numpy as np
I = np.identity(8)  # the identity matrix
I

array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])
```

but I'd like::

```
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just subtract the identity matrix from 1:

```
1 - np.identity(size)
```

Demo:

```
In [3]: np.identity(4)
Out[3]: 
array([[ 1.,  0.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  1.,  0.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  1.,  0.],
       [ 0.,  0.,  0.,  1.]])

In [4]: 1 - np.identity(4)
Out[4]: 
array([[ 0.,  1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  0.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  0.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.,  0.]])
```

Comment: Ooohh, that's easy and feeling a bit stupid here!! Ha ha. Tanks for your quick answer!!